# jQuery Slide down when clicked

Tags: jquery

I am using the follow jsfiddle to slide a div down when an element is clicked...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Initial variables
    var panel = $('#panel');
    var panelHeight = panel.height();

    // Set the height to 0
    panel.height(0);

    // Animate it to its initial size
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#panel').animate({'height' : panelHeight});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3fsQr/

I can't work out how to made it disappear again when the element is clicked once more.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I offer you an alternative:

set the `#panel` to `display: none;`

then you can use `slideToggle()` and you can keep that sliding effect: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3fsQr/13/)

if you'd like to continue using your way with `animate`, I've updated your fiddle so it works: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3fsQr/15/)

Answer (score 1):

Best Solution is to set the **#panel** div to `display:none` and then `slideToggle` it...

```
 $('a').click(function(e) {
     $('#panel').slideToggle();
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Better you can use jquery toggle.
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#panel').toggle();
    });
```

No need to keep height as '0' and original height everytime.